# determinant of symmetric matrix with zeros in diagonal is even

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Question is to prove that

> Determinant of a symmetric matrix of odd degree with integer entries  and zeros in the diagonal is even..

For $A=(a_{ij})$ with $a_{ii}=0$ and $a_{ij}=a_{ji}$..

Determinant is given by $$\sum_{\sigma}sgn(\sigma)\prod a_{i\sigma(i)}$$

Now, we can neglect $\sigma$ that fixes at least one element in $\{1,2\dots,n\}$ as we would then have $a_{ii}$ in that product which is zero..

Let $S$ be the collection of $\sigma$ that is remaining...

Let $\sigma\in S$ then $sgn(\sigma)=sgn(\sigma^{-1})$

$$\prod a_{i\sigma(i)}=\prod a_{\sigma(i)i}=\prod a_{j\sigma^{-1}(j)}$$

For pair $\sigma,\sigma^{-1}$ the product turns out to be same..

As $n$ is odd, there can be no element of order $2$ in $S$ so, $\sigma\neq \sigma^{-1}$

Suppose $\sigma$ is an element of order $2$.. We assume that $\sigma$ does not fix any element..

Start with $1$.. $\sigma(1)\neq 1$ we can suppose $\sigma(1)=2$..
As $\sigma^2=Id$  we should have $\sigma(2)=1$.. So, $\sigma=(1~2)\tau$

Start with $3$  $\sigma(3)\neq 3$ we can suppose $\sigma(3)=4$..
As $\sigma^2=Id$  we should have $\sigma(4)=3$.. So, $\sigma=(1~2)(3~4)\tau'$

Repeating this, we end up with $\sigma=(1~2)\cdots(2m-1~2m)(2m+1)$ a contradiction as we have assumed that $\sigma$ does not fix any element but here we have no option..

So, if $n$ is odd and $\sigma$ does not fix any element then $\sigma^2\neq Id$.. So, $\sigma\neq \sigma^{-1}$

So, sum has same number twice.. Thus determinant is even...

Help me to clear this...

Comment: What about the determinant of $\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}$?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin : Now?

Comment: You are correct that you can conclude from the information you have that $\sigma \neq \sigma^{-1}$; just might want to explain why, exactly?

Comment: @DustanLevenstein : I am sorry, I think i have said that..

Comment: Note that $\sigma := (12)$ is an element of $S_3$ ($n=3$ is odd) which satisfies $\sigma = \sigma^{-1}$.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein : Your example fixes one element so that does not come under $S$...

Comment: That's exactly right.

Comment: So, does that mean my justification has no gaps? @DustanLevenstein

Comment: You still need to explain why $\sigma \neq \sigma^{-1}$ in general. What you say is true; you just haven't justified it.

Comment: I do not know why it is true.. I just felt so... @DustanLevenstein I will try to figure it out.. Just to be clear, all that i have to do now is to prove that $\sigma\in S_n$ for  $n$ odd can not be of order $2$ if $\sigma(i)\neq i$ for any $i$..

Comment: That's correct. "I just felt so" is not a proof. :)

Comment: @DustanLevenstein : Yes YEs.. Definitely it is not a proof.. After seeing some pattern i came to that conclusion and now i have to figure it out why it is true.. Can you give some hint...

Comment: What can you say about the values that aren't fixed in an involution?

Comment: @DustanLevenstein I think i have fixed it now.. PLease see and let me know

Comment: Looks like you've got it now. If $\sigma=\sigma^{-1}$ and $\sigma\in S_n, n$ odd, then $\sigma$ has a fixed point. If you are familiar with the idea of viewing permutations as consisting of distinct cycles, then this follows immediately from the fact that you can only have 2-cycles and 1-cycles. Otherwise one needs to run through an argument just like yours (proving this fact!).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : Sir, Thanks for commenting on my question... I do not understand "if you are familiar with the idea of viewing permutations as consisting of distinct cycles then this follows"... I know that every permutation can be written as disjoint union of cycles.. Suppose $\sigma^2$ is identity then all these cycles should have order $2$ i.e., $2$ cycles. So, we left with $1$ element

Comment: I just hit "enter" too soon :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : Sir, I have written something close to your idea in my comment... :) Thanks again..

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to assume that the entries are integers?

Answer (score 1):

If we change the sign of any member of matrix the deterninant doesnt change modulo 2. So replace all $a_{ij}, i<j$ by $-a_{ij}$ and receive skew-simmetric matrix of odd order which determinant is even of course - because it becomes zero.

Comment: what is parity?

Comment: @cello, odd OR even

Comment: That would be another question to check that determinant of a skew symmetric matrix is even...

Comment: I have edit the post - so clear?

Comment: No it is not.. You just said it becomes zero..

Comment: Zero is even ...   Possibly you havent understand the start?     For integers $a$  and  $b$ consider  $a+b$  and  $a-b$ then either both even or both odd. Now look at formula of determinant. What happens if we replase any $a_{ij}$ by $-a_{ij}$?